# Referencing Object parameter for a function added throught Object.assign

Tags: javascript

I am trying to work out a way for writing reusable functions through "object.assign". In below code, I have noticed the bigsmile() function that I assigned through "Object.assign" has no access to the "name" parameters. But somehow sayhi() function can get "name" value correctly when called. What are the differences between the bigsime() and sayhi()? TKS!

```js
 
  const basicGreet = () => ({
    bigsmile: () => {
      console.log("big smile !!!");
      //console.log(name+"big smile !!!");  <-- this line cannot work
    }
  })

  const eng = (name:string) => ({
    sayhi:function(target:string){
      console.log(name + ": good morining " + target);
   }, 
  })

 let judy = (<any>Object).assign(basicGreet(), eng("Judy"));
 judy.sayhi("Jack");
 judy.bigsmile();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's typescript not js right? Or some other preprocessor?

Anyway I'm guessing that's working the same way as regular js. You're trying to access variable from the other scope (look for js closure). Scope of bigsmile doesn't have variable `name` in its scope and any enclosing it scope. If you want to have access to it you could do sth like this (I converted it to vanilla js):

```
  const basicGreet = () => ({
    bigsmile: function() {
      console.log("big smile !!!");
      console.log(this.name+"big smile !!!");
    },
  })

  const eng = (name) => ({
    sayhi: function(target) {
      console.log(name + ": good morining " + target); // for consistency you could use this.name
   },
   name,
  })

 let judy = Object.assign(basicGreet(), eng("Judy"));
 judy.sayhi("Jack");
 judy.bigsmile();
```

EDIT: if you want to have only functions in the object, you could create simple getter instead of `name`. Like:

```
const eng = (name) => ({
  sayhi: function(target) {
      console.log(this.getName() + ": good morining " + target);
   },
   getName: function() {
      return name;
  },
})
```